# update field using datediff

Tags: mysql, datediff

i have been trying to update a with the number of days using datediff.

The following statement works fine:

```
select DATEDIFF (date_stock_out,date_stock_in) from paddock
```

But when I try to update the third field in the table with the following statement, I am getting a syntax error:

```
update paddock set number_of_days = select DATEDIFF(date_stock_out,date_stock_in) from paddock
```

Where am I going wrong.

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: Consider to use [Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) on newer versions. Storing redundant data may lead to problems.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you do an `UPDATE` without having a `SELECT` right in the middle of it:

```
UPDATE paddock SET number_of_days=DATEDIFF(date_stock_out,date_stock_in)
```

It's implied you're working on `paddock` so there's no need to repeat yourself.

SQL statements each have their own unique syntax and restrictions on how, where and when they can be used. Check carefully before composing them together like you would functions in other more flexible programming languages.